# How to find inactive posts on Stack Overflow to earn the Archaeologist badge

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

How can I find posts which have been inactive for 6 months, as per the requirement for the Archaeologist badge? Is there some kind of search query or something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are [various SEDE queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=archaeologist%20) that could help you find posts eligible for Archaeologist, you can start with this one: [Which posts are eligible for Archaeologist edits?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77565/which-posts-are-eligible-for-archaeologist-edits-wip)

Keep in mind that:

1. SEDE data aren't exactly fresh, check the [front page](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to see when they were last updated for each site,
2. Editing en masse to get a badge is generally frowned up, especially if your edits are minor.

Comment: To clarify what @Yannis was saying in #2, Ankur, every edit you make bumps the post back up to the top of the active page, so if you make a lot of minor edits, someone *will* notice. So be sure your edits substantially improve the post. Be sure to fix *all* of the problems with the post if you're going to edit one. Good luck! :)

Comment: Interesting, running the query you suggest yields this: `The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.`

Comment: Yes, best to add a **TOP** clause to limit the number of results. e.g. *SELECT TOP 1000 P.Id AS*

Answer (score 10):

What I do is **sort questions by activity** and go to a random high-numbered page: if it had had activity within 6 monthes, if would be on a smaller-numbered page.